# $\varepsilon$-neighborhood set notation as $V_{\varepsilon}(a)$ and proof question

Tags: real-analysis, notation, proof-verification

Two questions regarding the set $V_{\varepsilon}(a)$.  It is defined in the book I am currently using as
$$V_{\varepsilon}(a)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\varepsilon\}$$
1).  Why the $V$?  I suppose there is a reason for using most notation and abbreviation (like using $\mathbb{R}$ for the reals, or $n$ to represent a natural number...)

2).  Let $\varepsilon>0, \delta>0, a\in\mathbb{R}$.  Show that $V_{\varepsilon}(a)\cap V_{\delta}(a)$ and $V_{\varepsilon}(a)\cup V_{\delta}(a)$ are $\gamma$-neighborhoods of $a$ for appropriate values of $\gamma$.

So I say, 
$$V_{\varepsilon}(a)\cap V_{\delta}(a)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\varepsilon \text{ and } |x-a|<\delta\}$$
$$=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\min{(\varepsilon,\delta)}\} $$
Letting $\gamma=\min{(\varepsilon,\delta)},$
$$=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-a|<\gamma\}=V_{\gamma}(a)$$
Therefore, $V_{\varepsilon}(a)\cap V_{\delta}(a)$ is a $\gamma$-neighborhood of $a$.

If this is all i need, I assume the union of two neighborhoods is also a $\gamma$-neighborhood by using the $\max$ function instead?

Comment: Someone use $D_{\epsilon}$ for disk or $B_{\epsilon}$ for ball. I dont know what $V$ is but I think that's fine as long as defined clearly.

Comment: You're on the right track. Notation is not standard for things like this. If there's a chance of confusion, then define it before using it. I would use $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for an interval because it doesn't require much of a definition (intervals are fairly standard.) $B_{r}(a)$ is often used generically, in any dimension, to designate the "ball" of radius $r$ centered at $a$, which could be a disk in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, an actual ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, etc.

Comment: Great!  I've seen the ball and disk reference (saw disk in some basic complex analysis stuff, although I've nat taken any).  I just wonder what the motivation behind the notation is, like there is something, some reason for choosing.  I like to know the reason because perhaps it will help me understand the author better if i knkow what he/she is thnking.  How does the proof look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I can only wager an educated guess, but it's likely that $V$ comes from the French *voisinage*.  I should note that I don't speak or read French, but according to google *voisinage* translates generally as "vicinity" or "neighborhood," and which seems to be the proper translation of the "neighborhood" in a mathematical context, based on a search of MathSciNet and Wikipedia ([English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28mathematics%29) and [French](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voisinage_%28math%C3%A9matiques%29)).

Since a decent amount of work in analysis and topology was published in German or French, it's not uncommon to see variables takes from words in these languages.  Some other examples that come to mind are $G_\delta$, from the German *Gebeit* and *Durchschnitt* ("open" and "intersection" repectively), $F_\sigma$ from the French *fermé* and *somme* ("closed" and "union"), and $K$ or $\mathbb{K}$ for a field, from the German *Korpus*.

As far as your proof is concerned, it's certainly correct.   You have the right idea for unions, too.  Note that depending on the definition, you might be proving more than is strictly necessary.  In particular, it depends on precisely what an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood is.  The most natural definition to me is that $U$ is a $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $U$ contains some $V_\varepsilon(a)$, i.e., if and only if there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $V_\varepsilon(a) \subseteq U$.  In this case, you've proven that $V_\varepsilon(a) \cap V_\delta(a)$ is in fact a set of the form $V_\gamma(a)$, so it's certainly a $\gamma$-neighborhood of $a$.

Comment: That is wonderful!  Thank you so much for the research.  That makes perfect sense about $V$, and it's nice to know.